# Programally multi-value param

Tags: karate

I need to make a request with a multi-value param,its value must be a very big array to test an api param validation. One of my implementation:

```
Scenario: filter_too_long_multivalue
    * def localPath = endPointBase + 'filter'
    * def generateLongParam =
    """ 
    function(){
        var paramValue = [];
        for(var idx = 0; idx<1002; idx++){          
            paramValue.push('r')
        }
        var params = {};
        params.pl = paramValue;
        return params;
    }
    """
    * def tooLongParam = generateLongParam()
    * print tooLongParam
    Given path localPath
    And params tooLongParam
    When method get
    Then match response == authorizationSchema.empty
```

Then the request is:
GET http://XXXXXXXXXXXXX?pl=%5Bobject+Array%5D

I have tried differents ways, but always the same result...
How can I obtain a weel formed request?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you have hit one of those edge cases, can you let me know if this works, I'll also see if this can be improved.

Sometimes what is returned by a JS function is not *exactly* the format that Karate likes. The workaround is to use `json` instead of `def` to type-convert - refer doc: https://github.com/intuit/karate#type-conversion

```
* def fun =
"""
function(){
    var temp = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {          
        temp.push('r');
    }
    return temp;
}
"""
* json array = fun()
Given url demoBaseUrl
And path 'echo'
And params { pl: '#(array)' }
When method get
Then status 200
```

Which resulted in:

```
1 > GET http://127.0.0.1:60146/echo?pl=r&pl=r&pl=r&pl=r&pl=r
```

Comment: Thank you, it works. It is a bit little elaborate, but it works, thank you very much.